# vimrc reference python3 path through system command

Tags: vim

For the `YouCompleteMe` plugin, I would like to set the parameter `g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter` in my vimrc to the path of the system python3 installation.

I am using `let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = system('which python3')` however that is invalid, as the `system(..)` returns the string of the python3 path in a separate buffer it seems like. What I mean is that I see

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python3

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

when I `:echo g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter`. I would expect just the path as string (i.e. `/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python3`). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is that `system()` will include the newline at the end of the command.

You can see that with the command:

```
:let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter
```

Which will show you:

```
g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter     /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python3^@
```

(The `^@` at the end represents the newline character.)

To fix that, just use a call to `trim()` around the `system()` call.

```
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = trim(system('which python3'))
```